# error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed - Error in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, ninja

I'm trying to run simple **c++** code on Qt Creator, but keep getting this error.

Comment: You must provide more information.

Comment: This happened for me when i added a .js file as part of the project.